# What is the best way to make an application have CPU and GPU computational backends

Tags: c++, cuda, eigen

I have an application that involves large amounts of matrix multiplications written using Eigen. I would like to make a GPU computational backend for it, while maintaining ability to run on the CPU only and be accelerated by MKL when available.

**The problem:**
Add a GPU computational backend in a way that shares as much code as possible as the CPU backend.

The easiest way to achieve GPU acceleration is through the use of Eigen-magma, however this is quite limited, since there are unnecessary copies back-and-forth from main memory to GPU memory on every operation, which limits the performance gain one could get from the GPU.

Knowing that I would have to ditch Eigen completely and rewrite the application but what would be the best way to do so, without having completely separate code paths for CPU and GPU computional backends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CUDA6 and the automatic managed memory feature you can easily avoid these extra copies by letting the drivers performing them when this is really necessary. It should be easy to adapt Eigen-magma to take advantage of that feature. This is way we plan to natively support CUDA within Eigen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you currently adding support for CUDA within Eigen? Could you point me to a discussion or a bug report? I would be interested to help.

Comment: Nothing started yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can take for the more generic case:

1. **CUDA** allows one to compile functions for both the host and the device (using `__host__ __device__`. A runtime switch would be able to change whether your resulting code has a for loop which iterates over elements calling your `__host__ __device__` function or a `__global__` function calling it.
2. **OpenACC** is probably the closest you'll get to a performance portable approach. It's directive based, and so the back-end has a bit more leeway to optimise for the targetted platform. That said, if you are targetting a specific architecture, you'll probably be able to outperform it with hand-coded implementations. How much so will vary with the problem and the programmer's ability. Being directive based, to compile for the host you just don't use the OpenACC flags.
3. **OpenCL**. OpenCL, like OpenACC, can target several platforms, but is parallelise explicitally (like CUDA) rather than using directives. The pros and cons of OpenCL vs CUDA are outside the scope of the question.

The inevitable problem with sharing code between different architectures is performance. You cannot expect code to be both fast and performance portable across X86/NVIDIA/AMD/Xeon Phi. With a single code intended to run on multiple architectures I think OpenACC is probably the best way to go, but you'll still be leaving a lot of performance on the table relative to code written with a specific architecture in mind.